# Using KnockoutJS Client Side, what does EF Server Side Code look like?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, knockout.js, client-server

I am using the Knockout: Contacts editor example http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html as the template to start my MVVM project.

At the top of my page I have a set of cascading combo boxes that allow the user to drill down to a master record. When the user clicks the refresh button, an AJAX call finds the corresponding detail records from the server matching the user's search criteria.  I load them into my viewmodel using ko.mapping.

My viewmodel is not as nested as the example, so I don't have anything at the "phone number" level. I do still want to add and delete records at the "first name / last name" level.

I am familiar with making AJAX calls to the server. I've looked at countless examples, but I still haven't found a good example of what the server side code should look like. Could someone point me toward an example that uses a list of objects like the example I am working with and what the VB.Net code looks like on the controller for adding, updating, and deleting database records using entity framework?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/using-web-api-with-entity-framework,-part-5 and the following page for EF. Also Filip's blog has good webapi topics http://www.strathweb.com/2012/03/serializing-entity-framework-objects-to-json-in-asp-net-web-api/#more-71

Comment: In these examples it uses code like:

EmployeeInfo employeeinfo = db.EmployeeInfoes.Find(id);

to locate the record to delete or update. Does Find() only look at primary keys? What if I have a composite key?

Comment: Another thing I don't quite understand, when I do I a PUT request, why do I need to pass the ID and the object to the server? Doesn't my object already have the ID? When you post or create an object you only send the object, then it looks like you return the newly created ID back to the client so the viewmodel can be updated correct?

Comment: I highly recommend using breezejs: http://www.breezejs.com/samples/todo-knockout

Comment: Breezejs is worth looking at but to answer your questions: find can handle composite keys, I had your thoughts about the put pattern initially but like how I can use the id to find the entity object and then update with the model not relying on its id being there